# Calculating the URL for a SOAP service call?

Tags: magento, soap, uri, method-call

Given a SOAP service at a Uri http://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 (Magento in this case)

How can I work out what URL is called when a particular method sales_order_invoice.list is invoked?

The reason for this question is that I need to be find out if the sites rewrite rules are interfering with the method call by rewriting the uri.

Is the uri one of:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/sales_order_invoice.list
http://www.example.com/index.php/api/sales_order_invoice.list
http://www.example.com/index.php/sales_order_invoice.list
http://www.example.com/sales_order_invoice.list
```

Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3):

It's something else entirely.  The API interface you're describing is a `REST`ful one.  Different URLs for different resources.  A SOAP API (Magento's or otherwise) doesn't work like that.  **All** API requests go through

```
 http://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1
```

The SOAP client will POST specifically formatted XML through the above endpoint URL, which will tell the the SOAP server which method needs to be called, and with what arguments.